# Access is denied error while trying to read vbs file from clearcase

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clearcase, web-setup-project

My .Net 2010 Development environment is properly configured with ClearCase. Checkins and Checkouts and rest of the operations work normally from within .Net IDE. The problem occurs when I try to build the web setup project.

In PreBuildEvent, I am executing .vbs file to change the build version number. If I try to build the web setup project without checking out the .vbs file, it fails saying :

```
Building file 'x:\Release\WhateverApp.msi'...
Starting pre-build events...
Access is denied.
```

If i checkout the .vbs file, it builds successfully.

Can someone point me in the right direction what should i look for to make sure it builds the project successfully without checkingout the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about a snapshot view (on `c:\...` even though you mounted said view on the `X:` drive letter), then you can [hijack the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165155/clearcase-checkout-and-modify-but-forbid-checkin/2166107#2166107) in order to avoid the checkout step.

By default in a ClearCase view, a non-checkout file is read only.
So that means you want to set the file attribute to read-write without notifying ClearCase.