# What are all the rules we should follow to reduce merging issues?

Tags: merge, clearcase, branching-and-merging, clearcase-ucm

After we migrated to Clearcase UCM , we have created stream for each sub team.

Often we are facing merging issue as people tend to work with old version without rebase. [ As rebase takes time]

Some times same files are being changed by 2 person in the same stream as they do unreserved checkout.

Is there any set of best practices to be followed in UCM so that we can reduce the merging issues?

[ I think this question should be the community wiki , but i don't know how to make it as wiki]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the concurrent modifications are mitigated by:

- UCM components definition: two people would work on different components (ie different file sets)
- or good communications (to avoid working on the same file at the same time)

There are also cases of modifying a generic config file in order to put a local path specific to one programmer's workstation, but in that case, an hijacked file is prefered to a checkout unreserved (see "[Clearcase: checkout and modify but forbid checkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165155/clearcase-checkout-and-modify-but-forbid-checkin)").