# How can I update my branch from main and accept all of their changes in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I grabbed a file and did: `rm -f theFile.C && ct update .` to watch it get reloaded. Then I went to a different snapshot view of main and ran `ct update .` and the files differ. I am very perplexed about this given after doing that I would expect them to be the same!

The EDCS for my "main snapshot" is:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/LATEST
load /ntrepo
```

and my EDCS for my branch is:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/branch_name/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch branch_name
element * /main/LATEST
load /ntrepo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an snapshot view, when the file doesn't match the expected version, the first thing to check is:

```
cleartool ls /path/to/parent/directory
```

And see what `cleartool` returns for that file.

For instance:

- it could be [hijacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165155/clearcase-checkout-and-modify-but-forbid-checkin/2166107#2166107), which means a `ct update .` wouldn't overwrite the locally modified file.
- it could have a different version on `branch_name`, since that selection rules comes *before* `/main/LATEST`.